# $8$ children of $4$ boys and $4$ girls are needed to form $2$ circles of $4$ children each. Find the number of different ways that this can be done.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My method would be to have $${8 \choose 4} \times 3! \times {4 \choose 4} \times 3! \times 2! $$

Well I multiply the $2!$ behind because I think circle 1 and circle 2 can be interchanged. However the answer is $$\dfrac{{8 \choose 4} \times 3! \times {4 \choose 4} \times 3!}{2!} $$

Do not really understand why they need to divide by $2$.

Comment: Your multiplication would be unnecessary because you are already directly generating all possible circle-1 variations, including those which are also generated as complements (that is, they appear as a circle-2 in other selections). From the answer, the circles are unnamed so having the circles (1,2) in configuration (X,Y) is regarded as the same as configuration (Y,X), so the duplication needs to be divided out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the solution given, this question is asking you to treat both circles equally. Thus, if you put people $A,B,C,D$ in circle $1$ and put people $E,F,G,H$ in circle $2$, this is the same as putting people $A,B,C,D$ in circle $2$ and people $E,F,G,H$ in circle $1$.

But the formula $\binom{8}{4}\times 3!\times\binom{4}{4}\times 3!$ treats these two arrangements as being distinct. Hence you must divide by $2$.

Comment: If the questions treats the two circles as distinct, may i know why i do not need to times $2!$. Does it already take into account of interchanging the two circles?

Comment: If the two circles are different, the answer is $\binom{8}{4}\times 3!\times\binom{4}{4}\times 3!$, since this counts each the combinations listed in my answer.